# Can't create several divs inside another div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create several divs inside the div which has the id "second".

```
<div>
    <div class="content" id="first" hidden></div>
    <div class="content" id="second" hidden></div>
    <div class="content" id="third" hidden></div>
</div>
```

I've tried the following function but it does not work.

```
  function createboard(){
    for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
      let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.className="column";
      newDiv.id="column";
      document.getElementById("second").appendChild(newDiv);
    }
  }
```

The function that removes the hidden attribute from the div

```
function hide_div(){
      if(document.getElementById("cavidades").value == "" || document.getElementById("sementes").value==""){
        alert("Preencha todos os dados de jogo antes de comeÃ§ar");
      }
      else{
        var start_div = document.getElementById("start_div");
        start_div.hidden=true;
        var login=document.getElementById("login");
        login.hidden=true;
        var first = document.getElementById("first");
        var second = document.getElementById("second");
        var third = document.getElementById("third");
        var inside=document.getElementById("inside");
        first.hidden=false;
        second.hidden=false;
        third.hidden=false;
        inside.hidden=false;
      }
```

Both are supposed to run when this button is clicked

```
<button hidden type="submit" id="start" onclick="hide_div() ; createboard()">Começar</button>
```

CSS of both divs

```
  div#second{
    float: left;
    background-color: lightgray;
    height: 500px;
    width: 500px;
    border: 5px solid black;
  }

  div#column{
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
    height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    border: 5px solid yellow;
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you think it's working?

Comment: FYI: it's not valid to have multiple elements with the same id, and your JS is assigning the same id to every element it creates. (this doesn't address the problem you're having, but it is a problem)

Comment: It's working, you just can't see them because they're inside a hidden DIV.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because your divs are hidden, try this:

```
  function createboard(){
    for(let i=0;i<10;i++){
      let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.className="column";
      document.getElementById("second").appendChild(newDiv);
      //just add this line 
      document.getElementById("second").hidden = false // to show the div 
    }
  }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that i changed the hidden to false on the div "second" before this. Nevertheless i've tried your code and it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Basically when i click a button it runs two functions, the createboard() function and one that changes the hidden value of the divs to true and they are visible indeed.

Comment: then maybe the problem is because of the `hide div` function, I just tried the code with out the if statement and its working, witch means the code inside the else block never execute that's why your divs are still hidden..

Comment: since I cant see your CSS code, another reason can be because of your CSS classname `column` , check if your divs are not hidden because of that classname as well

Comment: But i can see the divs, i've styled them and i can see them. I'll edit the css for the "second" div as well as for the column one.

Comment: do you always get an alert `Preencha todos os dados de jogo antes de comeÃ§ar` when you press the button ?

Comment: No, only if at least one of the elements is empty.

Comment: can you please check your browser console to see if there is any error with your code, just press F12 then go to console, then try to press the button and see if there is any error

Comment: There is no error and i think the divs are created and inside the "second" div, is it possible that they are behind it or something and that is why i cant see them?

Comment: it can be behind it! to verify just add z-index: 99; to your column classname. I think you should upload your whole html and js code so I can test it myself and see what wrong with it or upload your code on jsfiddle.net and share the link with me

Comment: I've tried adding z-index:99 and it also didnt work. Here's the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pedroccarvalho/9szqw0hy/3/     Thanks in advance!

Comment: the problem is inside your css, you wrote `div#column`  but you have to use `div .column` because column is a class not an id.
i updated the code, go to https://jsfiddle.net/mgswd905 and try it.

I just changed `div #column{ }`  to `div .column{ }` in your css code

Comment: Working now! Thank you so much!